Let H be a RKHS, show that $f(x)\overline{f(y)} \leq k(x,y)$
I have a question regarding a proof of Aronszajn's inclusion theorem in Paulsen's "An Introduction to the Theory of Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Spaces.
Let $X$ be a set and $\mathcal{H(K)}$ be the RKHS with kernel $K$. Kernels are defined as

$K(x, \cdot)\in \mathcal{H(K)}$ for all $x\in X$
Satisfying the reproducing property: $f(x) = \langle f, k(x,\cdot)\rangle$ for any $x\in X$.

Consider the following snippet from the book.



2 questions

How can one derive the bound $f(x)\overline{f(y)}\leq K_1(x, y)$?
How do we conclude that $f\in \mathcal{H}(K_2)$?

My attempt
We have to use the reproducing property. We get
$$
 f(x)\overline(f(y)) = \langle f, k(x, \cdot) \rangle \overline{\langle f, k(y, \cdot) \rangle} = \ldots ?
$$
(1.) I know that using Cauchy-Scwhwarz, we can bound the absolute value of an evalution of $f$. Also, I know that the norm of $f$ is equal to one, which would show up in the CS-inequality. I feel like this is a very trivial bound, but I cannot seem to figure it out.
(2.) We see that $|f(y)|^2 \leq c^2K_2(y, y)$, but from that, what can we conclude? Just because the evaluations of $f$ at $y$ is bounded by $K_2(y,y)$ alone does not need to imply that it is an element of $\mathcal{H}(K_2)$?
Thanks in advance!

The inequality symbols were confusing, pointwise comparison does not make any sense. Actually, $f(x)\overline{f(y)} \leq k(x, y)$ means that $k(x, y) - f(x)\overline{f(y)}$ is still a kernel function. This means that the matrix induced by $k(x, y) - f(x)\overline{f(y)}$ once fixing finitely many points in the domain is PSD. This equivalence can be found in Paulsen, but also in Theorem 2.1.11 in this master thesis. The proof involves the Interpolation theorem.
